# Package latest chrome-engine with your UWP build to avoid legacy Internet explorer issues in Web-View for PWA

Tags: c#, webview, uwp, webview2, chromium-portable

Package latest chrome-engine with your **UWP (Universal Windows Platform)** build to avoid legacy Internet explorer issues in ***Web-View***.

Let me explain the situation first:

I have a legacy UWP written in C# which opens a web application in web-view.
This web-view runs in legacy edge version - Microsoft Edge Legacy and some in IE11 as well.

My web-app got evolved as time progressed and we started using latest web features such as **PWA, Push Notifications, Offline support, latest CSS and JS features**.

Now the problem is that we want to publish the new version of UWP which should leverage all latest web advancement and changes done on our web app as I mentioned, but we don't have control over the clients system and we can't update the browser on client device.

So question is that how can I ship/include the light-weight chromium engine along with our new UWP build such that It uses shipped chromium browser engine instead of legacy edge browser and chromimum browser engine used as runtime browser for WebView?

Also I should be using the shipped version of **chromium browser run-time** only if clients are having IE11 or Legacy Edge browsers.

Is it possible or not or any other alternatives or suggestions are welcomed?

Comment: Latest Edge versions are Chromium based already

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Certainly they are but not older one's for which I want to provide an env or runtime of chrome-engine where my web-app can run without going into compatibility issues such service-workers, web-workers, Css-grid stylings not working,  I hope I am able to explain it.

Comment: Have you tried to use the [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/gettingstarted/winui) control from the Winui3? The WebView2 control uses Microsoft Edge (Chromium) as the rendering engine.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply package it a chromium based (via [pwaBuilder](https://www.pwabuilder.com/))

[according to them](https://blog.pwabuilder.com/docs/what-is-a-classic-package/)
A user needs to have Microsoft Edge installed. If Microsoft Edge is not installed the user will be prompted to install Edge first before installing the app. ([see here](https://winaero.com/microsoft-will-bring-chromium-based-edge-pwas-to-the-microsoft-store/))

When you submit your app to the Microsoft Store, you’ll upload both modern and classic app packages. Users will be offered to download whichever version their OS can support.